# rhino dynamic properties for Javascript

Tags: rhino

In Rhino, I can add specific properties by defining js... functions on a Java class. What I'd like is to define a catchall function that gets called if a program goes to reference a property that hasn't been otherwise defined. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to express this concept using native syntax, even using Rhino/Spidermonkey proprietary extensions like getters and setters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_Getters_and_Setters

However, JavaScript is fairly easy to extend, and so I think you could get something pretty close by adding a method to Object.prototype to support this more advanced style method invocation. The following would seem to do what you want:

```
Object.prototype.invokeMethodOrDefault = function(methodName,argsArray){
    if(this[methodName] && typeof this[methodName] == "function"){
        //invoke method with given arguments
        this[methodName].apply(this,argsArray)
    }else{
        this.defaultMethod.apply(this,argsArray)
    }
}

//add a defaultMethod noop that can be overridden for individual subclasses
Object.prototype.defaultMethod = function(){print("In default method")} 

//test it
foo = {
    helloWorld:function(){
        print("hello world!")
        print("args:")
        for(var i=0,l=arguments.length;i<l;i++){
            print(arguments[i]);
        } 
    }
}
foo.invokeMethodOrDefault("thisMethodDoesNotExist",[]) 

foo.invokeMethodOrDefault("helloWorld",["arg1","arg2"]) 


bar = {
    helloWorld2:function(){
        print("hello world2!")
        print("args:")
        for(var i=0,l=arguments.length;i<l;i++){
            print(arguments[i]);
        } 
    },
    defaultMethod:function(){
        print("in new default method")
    }
}

bar.invokeMethodOrDefault("thisMethodDoesNotExist",[]) 

bar.invokeMethodOrDefault("helloWorld2",["arg1","arg2"])
```

Which prints the following:

```
In default method
hello world!
args:
arg1
arg2
in new default method
hello world2!
args:
arg1
arg2
```

Comment: I was expecting to have to code this in Java, if it could be done at all!